# Beautifulsoup selects tag to Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, beautifulsoup

I am currently working on my quant project. Here is the thing I am expriencing: I need first-hand stock data to work with, I have a way of downloading stock csv files, however not the best way, because I don't wanna bomb the servers, let's say every two or three days with 1GB downloading.

What I have is a collection of all data of 5 year span. I wanna write a code that can update new records and `pd.concat()` it with the old ones, which is more effient way to do it.

this is the url and code i have:

```
url = 'http://quotes.money.163.com/service/chddata.html?code=1000001&start=20200101&end=20200401'
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) '
                  'AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
                  'Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36 QIHU 360SE'
}
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers).content
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response, 'lxml')
content = soup.select('p')[0]
```

and it returns:

```
<p>日期,股票代码,名称,...,流通市值,成交笔数
2020-04-01,000001,平安银行,...,2.50142285572e+11,2.50140272863e+11,32484
2020-03-31,000001,平安银行,...,2.48395752934e+11,2.48393754278e+11,32700
2020-03-30,000001,平安银行,...,2.51112581482e+11,2.51110560966e+11,37324
<..>
2020-01-06,000001,平安银行,...,3.3125902364e+11,3.31256358245e+11,48856
2020-01-03,000001,平安银行,...,3.33393674642e+11,3.33390992071e+11,58875
2020-01-02,000001,平安银行,...,3.2737784e+11,3.27375205834e+11,67692
</p>
```

my next line of code strucks me with troubles:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(content.prettify())[0]
```

or with another approach:

```
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response, 'lxml').get_text()
df1 = pd.DataFrame(soup)
```

returns:

```
ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!
```

I am not quite sure how to fix this issue.
Would you please take a look at it?
Thank you.

---

my alternative way would be downloading all recently records to my HDD, can concat them.

Comment: i dont think pandas dataframe can work with prettify. you have to extract the data cleanly, without the tags, before passing to pandas

Comment: @sammywemmy I did `soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response, 'lxml').get_text()` before, same error output.

Comment: u probably have to access the tags before get_text. ur data is probably btw some tags. my assumption is that you are familiar with BeautifulSoup

Comment: @sammywemmy Actually the url i provided is a sql server i assume, tags are very clean: `<html><body><p> ...data... </p></body></html>`. There are not much trouble with the tags, tbh.

Comment: @sammywemmy I can say that what I provided is a csv file, I could download each file to my HDD, I just want a simpler way to df.concat them. I really don't wanna download them.

Comment: @pepCoder what's the reason of using `prettify()` ?

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη guess `prettify()` shouldn't be considered in my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read data directly from online CSV

```py
import pandas as pd

URI = 'http://quotes.money.163.com/service/chddata.html?code=1000001&start=20200101&end=20200401'

df = pd.read_csv(URI, encoding='euc_kr')
```

I am not sure which encoding is used without testing but this code should return the values.

Comment: om(dear)g! i thought read_csv needs to provide an actual file location, didn't know link also works. thanks chief. in my scenario, `df = pd.read_csv(URI, encoding='gbk')`

Comment: `euc_kr` seams to work. I went digging https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/standard-encodings.html

Comment: @PraysonW.Daniel It is in chinese, I'm guessing 'gbk' or 'gb2312'